# Programmatically invalidated input cleares value in JSF / PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

After a business validation I want to set UIInput to invalid so it gets red and tells the user what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
 <p:outputLabel value="Label" for="input"/>
 <p:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.selectedEntity.input}"/>
 <p:commandButton value="#{msg['button.save']}" 
    icon="ui-icon-check" 
    action="#{bean.save()}" 
    update=":form, :growl" 
    oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('detailDlg').hide();"
 />

// bean code
UIInput c = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("form:input");
c.setValid(false);
```

The component gets red, but the text is also cleared. I can get it working with a little workaround:

```
Object value = c.getValue();
c.setValid(false);
c.setValue(value);
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Env: PrimeFaces 6.1, JSF Mojarra 2.2.14, Java 8, Spring Boot 1.5.4

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal JSF validator? No need anymore to manually fuss with findComponent(), setValid() etc.

Comment: The validation is done during save phase in service layer, because the data can be also imported from 2 other sources. I'm only able to catch "BusinessValidationException" with problematic fields...

Answer (score -1):

Your requirement is already covered by JSF, you don't need to do anything more. **The only thing here: use the standard validation way.**
If your are using Primefaces, when validation fails (and you update the form), the `ui-state-error` css class is added automatically to the invalid components.

If you want to show a custom error styles to the user, overwrite like this:

```
.ui-inputfield.ui-state-error, .ui-selectonemenu.ui-state-error {
    color: #dd6417 !important;
    border: 1px solid #dd6417 !important;
}
```

Now, the component is cleared because in the target bean, you're clearing the value or is a request bean.

If you need execute a business validation (access to DB and check something) the better way is create a hidden field with a JSF validator.

Comment: I know I can add css class, but I think it's a little tricky and I want to do it in "right way". I was just wondering, why is the input cleared. The bean is view scoped, I can see the value is set during debugging.. Unfortunately, as I wrote above, validation is done in save phase on backend, I'm not able to do it before save in a JSF validator.